# Bootstrap Popover placement incorrect when big horizontal page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have an issue with the Bootstrap popover

The placement of the popover seems to be working just fine when clicking on the first few items of the table. Now (horizontally)scroll to almost the end of the page and notice popovers are being positioned not above the button but elsewhere and the arrow is separated from the content (arrow is on correct position, content is not)

This is repeated a couple dozen times:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" title="title" data-content="content" data-placement="bottom">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Please look at my plunker project and notice when clicking on a popover which is located in the middel (or end) of the page, the content is not positioned correctly:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SIO4IMgtdknlMRNt3EQl?p=preview

Comment: Is known issue @Bootstrap https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19037